# How to retrieve JSON Object data MySQL select query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysql-json

I Have one table i.e discount_details. I have 2 columns are the ID , DiscountTotal. I want to sum the each record line total json object with in the D array (64,10,10 are the 1st record values)  . Like here 64,10,10 are the values,need to sum total value as 84 in the select query of MYSQL. I tried below examples but not working. Can please help on this issue.

```
SELECT  JSON_EXTRACT(`DiscountTotal`, '$.D') AS total FROM tablename
```

[image]

Comment: You must parse the array then aggregate. Use JSON_TABLE().

Comment: Can you please give exact select Query ? @Akina

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you choose to store data in JSON?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query:

```
SELECT s.SNO, sum(t.Value)
FROM tablename s, 
     JSON_TABLE(
         JSON_EXTRACT(`DiscountTotal`,'$[0].D'),
         "$[*]" COLUMNS(
           Value INT PATH "$"
         )
       ) t group by s.SNO
```